# This is my training and validation accuracy is there something wrong with code ? or data?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

This is my classification code with pytorch. 
it classify the image like cifar10.

The problem is I trained the classification model 
but when I submit the result it always has very low accuracy
so I'm thinking is there something wrong with my code or data

does my training accuracy and validation accuracy seem right?

```
EPOCHS = 40
SAVE_DIR = 'models'
MODEL_SAVE_PATH = os.path.join(SAVE_DIR, 'please.pt')
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
best_valid_loss = float('inf')

if not os.path.isdir(f'{SAVE_DIR}'):
    os.makedirs(f'{SAVE_DIR}')
print("start")
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    print('================================',epoch ,'================================')
    for i , (train_idx, valid_idx) in enumerate(zip(train_indexes, valid_indexes)):
        print(i,train_idx,valid_idx)
        ## create iterator objects for train and valid datasets
        trainloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler= SubsetRandomSampler(train_idx))
        valloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=SubsetRandomSampler(valid_idx))

        train_loss, train_acc = train(model, device, trainloader, optimizer, criterion)
        valid_loss, valid_acc = evaluate(model, device, valloader, criterion)

        if valid_loss < best_valid_loss:
            best_valid_loss = valid_loss
            torch.save(model.state_dict(), MODEL_SAVE_PATH)

        print(f'| Epoch: {epoch+1:02} | Train Loss: {train_loss:.3f} | Train Acc: {train_acc*100:05.2f}% | Val. Loss: {valid_loss:.3f} | Val. Acc: {valid_acc*100:05.2f}% |')
```

And here is my train and validation accuracy
with this log is there something wrong with data or code?

```
start
================================ 0 ================================ 0 [  451   452   453 ... 21514 21515 21516] [    0     1     2 ... 18402 18403 18404] | Epoch: 01 | Train Loss: 0.111 | Train Acc: 96.11% | Val. Loss: 0.122 | Val. Acc: 95.92% | 1 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  451   452   453 ... 18847 18848 18849] | Epoch: 01 | Train Loss: 0.102 | Train Acc: 96.54% | Val. Loss: 0.118 | Val. Acc:
96.28% | 2 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  902   903   904 ... 19292 19293 19294] | Epoch: 01 | Train Loss: 0.091 | Train Acc: 96.79% | Val. Loss: 0.122 | Val. Acc: 95.53% | 3 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1353  1354  1355 ... 19737 19738 19739] | Epoch: 01 | Train Loss: 0.092 | Train Acc: 96.87% | Val. Loss: 0.117 | Val. Acc: 95.82% | 4 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1803  1804  1805 ... 20182 20183 20184] | Epoch: 01 | Train Loss: 0.093 | Train Acc: 96.82% | Val. Loss: 0.129 | Val. Acc: 95.71% | 5 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2253  2254  2255 ... 20626 20627 20628] | Epoch: 01 | Train Loss: 0.090 | Train Acc: 96.83% | Val. Loss: 0.136 | Val. Acc: 95.17% | 6 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2703  2704  2705 ... 21070 21071 21072] | Epoch: 01 | Train Loss: 0.094 | Train Acc: 96.69% | Val. Loss: 0.112 | Val. Acc: 95.74% | 7 [    0     1     2 ... 21070 21071 21072] [ 3153  3154  3155 ... 21514 21515 21516] | Epoch: 01 | Train Loss: 0.090 | Train Acc: 96.80% | Val. Loss: 0.134 | Val. Acc: 94.96% |
================================ 1 ================================ 0 [  451   452   453 ... 21514 21515 21516] [    0     1     2 ... 18402 18403 18404] | Epoch: 02 | Train Loss: 0.092 | Train Acc: 96.96% | Val. Loss: 0.078 | Val. Acc: 97.16% | 1 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  451   452   453 ... 18847 18848 18849] | Epoch: 02 | Train Loss: 0.090 | Train Acc: 96.77% | Val. Loss: 0.115 | Val. Acc:
95.53% | 2 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  902   903   904 ... 19292 19293 19294] | Epoch: 02 | Train Loss: 0.083 | Train Acc: 97.17% | Val. Loss: 0.105 | Val. Acc: 96.21% | 3 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1353  1354  1355 ... 19737 19738 19739] | Epoch: 02 | Train Loss: 0.091 | Train Acc: 96.71% | Val. Loss: 0.162 | Val. Acc: 94.15% | 4 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1803  1804  1805 ... 20182 20183 20184] | Epoch: 02 | Train Loss: 0.077 | Train Acc: 97.30% | Val. Loss: 0.124 | Val. Acc: 95.10% | 5 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2253  2254  2255 ... 20626 20627 20628] | Epoch: 02 | Train Loss: 0.082 | Train Acc: 97.13% | Val. Loss: 0.100 | Val. Acc: 96.45% | 6 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2703  2704  2705 ... 21070 21071 21072] | Epoch: 02 | Train Loss: 0.086 | Train Acc: 96.99% | Val. Loss: 0.121 | Val. Acc: 95.35% | 7 [    0     1     2 ... 21070 21071 21072] [ 3153  3154  3155 ... 21514 21515 21516] | Epoch: 02 | Train Loss: 0.078 | Train Acc: 97.26% | Val. Loss: 0.132 | Val. Acc: 95.49% |
================================ 2 ================================ 0 [  451   452   453 ... 21514 21515 21516] [    0     1     2 ... 18402 18403 18404] | Epoch: 03 | Train Loss: 0.081 | Train Acc: 97.10% | Val. Loss: 0.108 | Val. Acc: 96.70% | 1 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  451   452   453 ... 18847 18848 18849] | Epoch: 03 | Train Loss: 0.085 | Train Acc: 97.04% | Val. Loss: 0.098 | Val. Acc:
96.52% | 2 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  902   903   904 ... 19292 19293 19294] | Epoch: 03 | Train Loss: 0.080 | Train Acc: 97.27% | Val. Loss: 0.121 | Val. Acc: 95.99% | 3 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1353  1354  1355 ... 19737 19738 19739] | Epoch: 03 | Train Loss: 0.075 | Train Acc: 97.43% | Val. Loss: 0.107 | Val. Acc: 96.17% | 4 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1803  1804  1805 ... 20182 20183 20184] | Epoch: 03 | Train Loss: 0.076 | Train Acc: 97.39% | Val. Loss: 0.096 | Val. Acc: 96.35% | 5 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2253  2254  2255 ... 20626 20627 20628] | Epoch: 03 | Train Loss: 0.076 | Train Acc: 97.32% | Val. Loss: 0.113 | Val. Acc: 96.06% | 6 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2703  2704  2705 ... 21070 21071 21072] | Epoch: 03 | Train Loss: 0.079 | Train Acc: 97.21% | Val. Loss: 0.076 | Val. Acc: 97.30% | 7 [    0     1     2 ... 21070 21071 21072] [ 3153  3154  3155 ... 21514 21515 21516] | Epoch: 03 | Train Loss: 0.071 | Train Acc: 97.45% | Val. Loss: 0.080 | Val. Acc: 97.05% |
================================ 3 ================================ 0 [  451   452   453 ... 21514 21515 21516] [    0     1     2 ... 18402 18403 18404] | Epoch: 04 | Train Loss: 0.077 | Train Acc: 97.24% | Val. Loss: 0.091 | Val. Acc: 96.95% | 1 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  451   452   453 ... 18847 18848 18849] | Epoch: 04 | Train Loss: 0.073 | Train Acc: 97.45% | Val. Loss: 0.122 | Val. Acc:
95.78% | 2 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  902   903   904 ... 19292 19293 19294] | Epoch: 04 | Train Loss: 0.073 | Train Acc: 97.29% | Val. Loss: 0.088 | Val. Acc: 97.05% | 3 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1353  1354  1355 ... 19737 19738 19739] | Epoch: 04 | Train Loss: 0.071 | Train Acc: 97.56% | Val. Loss: 0.099 | Val. Acc: 96.74% | 4 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1803  1804  1805 ... 20182 20183 20184] | Epoch: 04 | Train Loss: 0.090 | Train Acc: 96.85% | Val. Loss: 0.127 | Val. Acc: 95.71% | 5 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2253  2254  2255 ... 20626 20627 20628] | Epoch: 04 | Train Loss: 0.073 | Train Acc: 97.30% | Val. Loss: 0.099 | Val. Acc: 96.56% | 6 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2703  2704  2705 ... 21070 21071 21072] | Epoch: 04 | Train Loss: 0.065 | Train Acc: 97.66% | Val. Loss: 0.086 | Val. Acc: 97.05% | 7 [    0     1     2 ... 21070 21071 21072] [ 3153  3154  3155 ... 21514 21515 21516] | Epoch: 04 | Train Loss: 0.073 | Train Acc: 97.41% | Val. Loss: 0.073 | Val. Acc: 97.48% |
================================ 4 ================================ 0 [  451   452   453 ... 21514 21515 21516] [    0     1     2 ... 18402 18403 18404] | Epoch: 05 | Train Loss: 0.062 | Train Acc: 97.85% | Val. Loss: 0.097 | Val. Acc: 96.85% | 1 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  451   452   453 ... 18847 18848 18849] | Epoch: 05 | Train Loss: 0.065 | Train Acc: 97.77% | Val. Loss: 0.088 | Val. Acc:
96.70% | 2 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  902   903   904 ... 19292 19293 19294] | Epoch: 05 | Train Loss: 0.065 | Train Acc: 97.74% | Val. Loss: 0.100 | Val. Acc: 96.21% | 3 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1353  1354  1355 ... 19737 19738 19739] | Epoch: 05 | Train Loss: 0.061 | Train Acc: 97.88% | Val. Loss: 0.081 | Val. Acc: 96.95% | 4 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1803  1804  1805 ... 20182 20183 20184] | Epoch: 05 | Train Loss: 0.067 | Train Acc: 97.64% | Val. Loss: 0.076 | Val. Acc: 97.34% | 5 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2253  2254  2255 ... 20626 20627 20628] | Epoch: 05 | Train Loss: 0.063 | Train Acc: 97.79% | Val. Loss: 0.086 | Val. Acc: 97.02% | 6 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2703  2704  2705 ... 21070 21071 21072] | Epoch: 05 | Train Loss: 0.066 | Train Acc: 97.69% | Val. Loss: 0.097 | Val. Acc: 96.73% | 7 [    0     1     2 ... 21070 21071 21072] [ 3153  3154  3155 ... 21514 21515 21516] | Epoch: 05 | Train Loss: 0.061 | Train Acc: 97.79% | Val. Loss: 0.072 | Val. Acc: 97.69% |
================================ 5 ================================ 0 [  451   452   453 ... 21514 21515 21516] [    0     1     2 ... 18402 18403 18404] | Epoch: 06 | Train Loss: 0.057 | Train Acc: 98.07% | Val. Loss: 0.078 | Val. Acc: 97.52% | 1 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  451   452   453 ... 18847 18848 18849] | Epoch: 06 | Train Loss: 0.057 | Train Acc: 97.97% | Val. Loss: 0.101 | Val. Acc:
96.42% | 2 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  902   903   904 ... 19292 19293 19294] | Epoch: 06 | Train Loss: 0.062 | Train Acc: 97.76% | Val. Loss: 0.067 | Val. Acc: 97.55% | 3 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1353  1354  1355 ... 19737 19738 19739] | Epoch: 06 | Train Loss: 0.062 | Train Acc: 97.76% | Val. Loss: 0.062 | Val. Acc: 98.01% | 4 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1803  1804  1805 ... 20182 20183 20184] | Epoch: 06 | Train Loss: 0.062 | Train Acc: 97.87% | Val. Loss: 0.055 | Val. Acc: 98.12% | 5 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2253  2254  2255 ... 20626 20627 20628] | Epoch: 06 | Train Loss: 0.056 | Train Acc: 98.10% | Val. Loss: 0.086 | Val. Acc: 97.20% | 6 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2703  2704  2705 ... 21070 21071 21072] | Epoch: 06 | Train Loss: 0.056 | Train Acc: 98.00% | Val. Loss: 0.070 | Val. Acc: 97.69% | 7 [    0     1     2 ... 21070 21071 21072] [ 3153  3154  3155 ... 21514 21515 21516] | Epoch: 06 | Train Loss: 0.062 | Train Acc: 97.88% | Val. Loss: 0.058 | Val. Acc: 98.12% |
================================ 6 ================================ 0 [  451   452   453 ... 21514 21515 21516] [    0     1     2 ... 18402 18403 18404] | Epoch: 07 | Train Loss: 0.061 | Train Acc: 97.86% | Val. Loss: 0.052 | Val. Acc: 98.23% | 1 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  451   452   453 ... 18847 18848 18849] | Epoch: 07 | Train Loss: 0.060 | Train Acc: 97.91% | Val. Loss: 0.056 | Val. Acc:
97.80% | 2 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  902   903   904 ... 19292 19293 19294] | Epoch: 07 | Train Loss: 0.053 | Train Acc: 98.11% | Val. Loss: 0.065 | Val. Acc: 97.48% | 3 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1353  1354  1355 ... 19737 19738 19739] | Epoch: 07 | Train Loss: 0.056 | Train Acc: 98.01% | Val. Loss: 0.095 | Val. Acc: 96.56% | 4 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1803  1804  1805 ... 20182 20183 20184] | Epoch: 07 | Train Loss: 0.057 | Train Acc: 97.96% | Val. Loss: 0.071 | Val. Acc: 97.20% | 5 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2253  2254  2255 ... 20626 20627 20628] | Epoch: 07 | Train Loss: 0.057 | Train Acc: 98.16% | Val. Loss: 0.067 | Val. Acc: 97.87% | 6 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2703  2704  2705 ... 21070 21071 21072] | Epoch: 07 | Train Loss: 0.055 | Train Acc: 98.05% | Val. Loss: 0.062 | Val. Acc: 97.83% | 7 [    0     1     2 ... 21070 21071 21072] [ 3153  3154  3155 ... 21514 21515 21516] | Epoch: 07 | Train Loss: 0.053 | Train Acc: 98.17% | Val. Loss: 0.068 | Val. Acc: 97.76% |
================================ 7 ================================ 0 [  451   452   453 ... 21514 21515 21516] [    0     1     2 ... 18402 18403 18404] | Epoch: 08 | Train Loss: 0.053 | Train Acc: 98.17% | Val. Loss: 0.061 | Val. Acc: 97.98% | 1 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  451   452   453 ... 18847 18848 18849] | Epoch: 08 | Train Loss: 0.053 | Train Acc: 98.15% | Val. Loss: 0.054 | Val. Acc:
98.33% | 2 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  902   903   904 ... 19292 19293 19294] | Epoch: 08 | Train Loss: 0.051 | Train Acc: 98.31% | Val. Loss: 0.067 | Val. Acc: 97.48% | 3 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1353  1354  1355 ... 19737 19738 19739] | Epoch: 08 | Train Loss: 0.049 | Train Acc: 98.26% | Val. Loss: 0.053 | Val. Acc: 98.33% | 4 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1803  1804  1805 ... 20182 20183 20184] | Epoch: 08 | Train Loss: 0.058 | Train Acc: 97.91% | Val. Loss: 0.066 | Val. Acc: 97.62% | 5 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2253  2254  2255 ... 20626 20627 20628] | Epoch: 08 | Train Loss: 0.054 | Train Acc: 98.10% | Val. Loss: 0.069 | Val. Acc: 97.48% | 6 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2703  2704  2705 ... 21070 21071 21072] | Epoch: 08 | Train Loss: 0.063 | Train Acc: 97.80% | Val. Loss: 0.058 | Val. Acc: 97.83% | 7 [    0     1     2 ... 21070 21071 21072] [ 3153  3154  3155 ... 21514 21515 21516] | Epoch: 08 | Train Loss: 0.050 | Train Acc: 98.27% | Val. Loss: 0.053 | Val. Acc: 98.15% |
================================ 8 ================================ 0 [  451   452   453 ... 21514 21515 21516] [    0     1     2 ... 18402 18403 18404] | Epoch: 09 | Train Loss: 0.050 | Train Acc: 98.35% | Val. Loss: 0.059 | Val. Acc: 98.22% | 1 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  451   452   453 ... 18847 18848 18849] | Epoch: 09 | Train Loss: 0.045 | Train Acc: 98.35% | Val. Loss: 0.047 | Val. Acc:
98.09% | 2 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  902   903   904 ... 19292 19293 19294] | Epoch: 09 | Train Loss: 0.047 | Train Acc: 98.42% | Val. Loss: 0.052 | Val. Acc: 98.37% | 3 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1353  1354  1355 ... 19737 19738 19739] | Epoch: 09 | Train Loss: 0.050 | Train Acc: 98.27% | Val. Loss: 0.077 | Val. Acc: 97.87% | 4 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1803  1804  1805 ... 20182 20183 20184] | Epoch: 09 | Train Loss: 0.050 | Train Acc: 98.27% | Val. Loss: 0.053 | Val. Acc: 98.05% | 5 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2253  2254  2255 ... 20626 20627 20628] | Epoch: 09 | Train Loss: 0.046 | Train Acc: 98.42% | Val. Loss: 0.072 | Val. Acc: 97.62% | 6 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2703  2704  2705 ... 21070 21071 21072] | Epoch: 09 | Train Loss: 0.050 | Train Acc: 98.21% | Val. Loss: 0.078 | Val. Acc: 97.23% | 7 [    0     1     2 ... 21070 21071 21072] [ 3153  3154  3155 ... 21514 21515 21516] | Epoch: 09 | Train Loss: 0.053 | Train Acc: 98.11% | Val. Loss: 0.062 | Val. Acc: 97.90% |
================================ 9 ================================ 0 [  451   452   453 ... 21514 21515 21516] [    0     1     2 ... 18402 18403 18404] | Epoch: 10 | Train Loss: 0.051 | Train Acc: 98.18% | Val. Loss: 0.065 | Val. Acc: 98.01% | 1 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  451   452   453 ... 18847 18848 18849] | Epoch: 10 | Train Loss: 0.049 | Train Acc: 98.33% | Val. Loss: 0.096 | Val. Acc:
96.81% | 2 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  902   903   904 ... 19292 19293 19294] | Epoch: 10 | Train Loss: 0.050 | Train Acc: 98.37% | Val. Loss: 0.056 | Val. Acc: 98.23% | 3 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1353  1354  1355 ... 19737 19738 19739] | Epoch: 10 | Train Loss: 0.044 | Train Acc: 98.50% | Val. Loss: 0.053 | Val. Acc: 98.37% | 4 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1803  1804  1805 ... 20182 20183 20184] | Epoch: 10 | Train Loss: 0.041 | Train Acc: 98.51% | Val. Loss: 0.045 | Val. Acc: 98.51% | 5 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2253  2254  2255 ... 20626 20627 20628] | Epoch: 10 | Train Loss: 0.043 | Train Acc: 98.46% | Val. Loss: 0.060 | Val. Acc: 98.01% | 6 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2703  2704  2705 ... 21070 21071 21072] | Epoch: 10 | Train Loss: 0.046 | Train Acc: 98.39% | Val. Loss: 0.051 | Val. Acc: 98.08% | 7 [    0     1     2 ... 21070 21071 21072] [ 3153  3154  3155 ... 21514 21515 21516] | Epoch: 10 | Train Loss: 0.045 | Train Acc: 98.40% | Val. Loss: 0.059 | Val. Acc: 98.26% |
================================ 10 ================================ 0 [  451   452   453 ... 21514 21515 21516] [    0     1     2 ... 18402 18403 18404] | Epoch: 11 | Train Loss: 0.041 | Train Acc: 98.56% | Val. Loss: 0.052 | Val. Acc: 98.47% | 1 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  451   452   453 ... 18847 18848 18849] | Epoch: 11 | Train Loss: 0.047 | Train Acc: 98.35% | Val. Loss: 0.061 | Val. Acc:
97.91% | 2 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  902   903   904 ... 19292 19293 19294] | Epoch: 11 | Train Loss: 0.047 | Train Acc: 98.42% | Val. Loss: 0.053 | Val. Acc: 98.33% | 3 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1353  1354  1355 ... 19737 19738 19739] | Epoch: 11 | Train Loss: 0.039 | Train Acc: 98.65% | Val. Loss: 0.046 | Val. Acc: 98.47% | 4 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1803  1804  1805 ... 20182 20183 20184] | Epoch: 11 | Train Loss: 0.034 | Train Acc: 98.83% | Val. Loss: 0.056 | Val. Acc: 98.19% | 5 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2253  2254  2255 ... 20626 20627 20628] | Epoch: 11 | Train Loss: 0.047 | Train Acc: 98.44% | Val. Loss: 0.062 | Val. Acc: 97.70% | 6 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2703  2704  2705 ... 21070 21071 21072] | Epoch: 11 | Train Loss: 0.040 | Train Acc: 98.63% | Val. Loss: 0.039 | Val. Acc: 98.69% | 7 [    0     1     2 ... 21070 21071 21072] [ 3153  3154  3155 ... 21514 21515 21516] | Epoch: 11 | Train Loss: 0.038 | Train Acc: 98.70% | Val. Loss: 0.043 | Val. Acc: 98.40% |
================================ 11 ================================ 0 [  451   452   453 ... 21514 21515 21516] [    0     1     2 ... 18402 18403 18404] | Epoch: 12 | Train Loss: 0.039 | Train Acc: 98.65% | Val. Loss: 0.060 | Val. Acc: 97.87% | 1 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  451   452   453 ... 18847 18848 18849] | Epoch: 12 | Train Loss: 0.043 | Train Acc: 98.54% | Val. Loss: 0.049 | Val. Acc:
98.23% | 2 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  902   903   904 ... 19292 19293 19294] | Epoch: 12 | Train Loss: 0.045 | Train Acc: 98.39% | Val. Loss: 0.069 | Val. Acc: 97.63% | 3 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1353  1354  1355 ... 19737 19738 19739] | Epoch: 12 | Train Loss: 0.044 | Train Acc: 98.43% | Val. Loss: 0.052 | Val. Acc: 97.80% | 4 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1803  1804  1805 ... 20182 20183 20184] | Epoch: 12 | Train Loss: 0.040 | Train Acc: 98.54% | Val. Loss: 0.061 | Val. Acc: 98.01% | 5 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2253  2254  2255 ... 20626 20627 20628] | Epoch: 12 | Train Loss: 0.038 | Train Acc: 98.70% | Val. Loss: 0.052 | Val. Acc: 98.26% | 6 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2703  2704  2705 ... 21070 21071 21072] | Epoch: 12 | Train Loss: 0.043 | Train Acc: 98.56% | Val. Loss: 0.056 | Val. Acc: 98.01% | 7 [    0     1     2 ... 21070 21071 21072] [ 3153  3154  3155 ... 21514 21515 21516] | Epoch: 12 | Train Loss: 0.045 | Train Acc: 98.43% | Val. Loss: 0.043 | Val. Acc: 98.44% |
================================ 12 ================================ 0 [  451   452   453 ... 21514 21515 21516] [    0     1     2 ... 18402 18403 18404] | Epoch: 13 | Train Loss: 0.045 | Train Acc: 98.40% | Val. Loss: 0.060 | Val. Acc: 97.94% | 1 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  451   452   453 ... 18847 18848 18849] | Epoch: 13 | Train Loss: 0.042 | Train Acc: 98.52% | Val. Loss: 0.062 | Val. Acc:
97.73% | 2 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  902   903   904 ... 19292 19293 19294] | Epoch: 13 | Train Loss: 0.038 | Train Acc: 98.66% | Val. Loss: 0.047 | Val. Acc: 98.23% | 3 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1353  1354  1355 ... 19737 19738 19739] | Epoch: 13 | Train Loss: 0.040 | Train Acc: 98.61% | Val. Loss: 0.045 | Val. Acc: 98.16% | 4 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1803  1804  1805 ... 20182 20183 20184] | Epoch: 13 | Train Loss: 0.033 | Train Acc: 98.82% | Val. Loss: 0.050 | Val. Acc: 98.37% | 5 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2253  2254  2255 ... 20626 20627 20628] | Epoch: 13 | Train Loss: 0.042 | Train Acc: 98.60% | Val. Loss: 0.045 | Val. Acc: 98.12% | 6 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2703  2704  2705 ... 21070 21071 21072] | Epoch: 13 | Train Loss: 0.040 | Train Acc: 98.70% | Val. Loss: 0.043 | Val. Acc: 98.65% | 7 [    0     1     2 ... 21070 21071 21072] [ 3153  3154  3155 ... 21514 21515 21516] | Epoch: 13 | Train Loss: 0.038 | Train Acc: 98.63% | Val. Loss: 0.065 | Val. Acc: 97.80% |
================================ 13 ================================ 0 [  451   452   453 ... 21514 21515 21516] [    0     1     2 ... 18402 18403 18404] | Epoch: 14 | Train Loss: 0.041 | Train Acc: 98.62% | Val. Loss: 0.038 | Val. Acc: 98.76% | 1 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  451   452   453 ... 18847 18848 18849] | Epoch: 14 | Train Loss: 0.039 | Train Acc: 98.74% | Val. Loss: 0.056 | Val. Acc:
98.40% | 2 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  902   903   904 ... 19292 19293 19294] | Epoch: 14 | Train Loss: 0.037 | Train Acc: 98.68% | Val. Loss: 0.043 | Val. Acc: 98.30% | 3 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1353  1354  1355 ... 19737 19738 19739] | Epoch: 14 | Train Loss: 0.039 | Train Acc: 98.69% | Val. Loss: 0.041 | Val. Acc: 98.58% | 4 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1803  1804  1805 ... 20182 20183 20184] | Epoch: 14 | Train Loss: 0.039 | Train Acc: 98.70% | Val. Loss: 0.038 | Val. Acc: 98.65% | 5 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2253  2254  2255 ... 20626 20627 20628] | Epoch: 14 | Train Loss: 0.035 | Train Acc: 98.77% | Val. Loss: 0.046 | Val. Acc: 98.40% | 6 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2703  2704  2705 ... 21070 21071 21072] | Epoch: 14 | Train Loss: 0.039 | Train Acc: 98.70% | Val. Loss: 0.043 | Val. Acc: 98.37% | 7 [    0     1     2 ... 21070 21071 21072] [ 3153  3154  3155 ... 21514 21515 21516] | Epoch: 14 | Train Loss: 0.034 | Train Acc: 98.87% | Val. Loss: 0.045 | Val. Acc: 98.37% |
================================ 14 ================================ 0 [  451   452   453 ... 21514 21515 21516] [    0     1     2 ... 18402 18403 18404] | Epoch: 15 | Train Loss: 0.039 | Train Acc: 98.68% | Val. Loss: 0.046 | Val. Acc: 98.23% | 1 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  451   452   453 ... 18847 18848 18849] | Epoch: 15 | Train Loss: 0.038 | Train Acc: 98.70% | Val. Loss: 0.046 | Val. Acc:
98.54% | 2 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  902   903   904 ... 19292 19293 19294] | Epoch: 15 | Train Loss: 0.035 | Train Acc: 98.80% | Val. Loss: 0.072 | Val. Acc: 97.73% | 3 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1353  1354  1355 ... 19737 19738 19739] | Epoch: 15 | Train Loss: 0.041 | Train Acc: 98.69% | Val. Loss: 0.044 | Val. Acc: 98.44% | 4 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1803  1804  1805 ... 20182 20183 20184] | Epoch: 15 | Train Loss: 0.031 | Train Acc: 98.87% | Val. Loss: 0.047 | Val. Acc: 98.58% | 5 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2253  2254  2255 ... 20626 20627 20628] | Epoch: 15 | Train Loss: 0.036 | Train Acc: 98.73% | Val. Loss: 0.029 | Val. Acc: 98.97% | 6 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2703  2704  2705 ... 21070 21071 21072] | Epoch: 15 | Train Loss: 0.038 | Train Acc: 98.65% | Val. Loss: 0.046 | Val. Acc: 98.44% | 7 [    0     1     2 ... 21070 21071 21072] [ 3153  3154  3155 ... 21514 21515 21516] | Epoch: 15 | Train Loss: 0.035 | Train Acc: 98.78% | Val. Loss: 0.041 | Val. Acc: 98.76% |
================================ 15 ================================ 0 [  451   452   453 ... 21514 21515 21516] [    0     1     2 ... 18402 18403 18404] | Epoch: 16 | Train Loss: 0.040 | Train Acc: 98.66% | Val. Loss: 0.043 | Val. Acc: 98.55% | 1 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  451   452   453 ... 18847 18848 18849] | Epoch: 16 | Train Loss: 0.033 | Train Acc: 98.86% | Val. Loss: 0.037 | Val. Acc:
98.72% | 2 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [  902   903   904 ... 19292 19293 19294] | Epoch: 16 | Train Loss: 0.033 | Train Acc: 98.82% | Val. Loss: 0.034 | Val. Acc: 98.58% | 3 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1353  1354  1355 ... 19737 19738 19739] | Epoch: 16 | Train Loss: 0.033 | Train Acc: 98.77% | Val. Loss: 0.046 | Val. Acc: 98.26% | 4 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 1803  1804  1805 ... 20182 20183 20184] | Epoch: 16 | Train Loss: 0.036 | Train Acc: 98.66% | Val. Loss: 0.031 | Val. Acc: 99.11% | 5 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2253  2254  2255 ... 20626 20627 20628] | Epoch: 16 | Train Loss: 0.040 | Train Acc: 98.65% | Val. Loss: 0.040 | Val. Acc: 98.90% | 6 [    0     1     2 ... 21514 21515 21516] [ 2703  2704  2705 ... 21070 21071 21072] | Epoch: 16 | Train Loss: 0.033 | Train Acc: 98.91% | Val. Loss: 0.037 | Val. Acc: 98.76% | 7 [    0     1     2 ... 21070 21071 21072] [ 3153  3154  3155 ... 21514 21515 21516] | Epoch: 16 | Train Loss: 0.032 | Train Acc: 98.90% | Val. Loss: 0.040 | Val. Acc: 98.65% |
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a seperate dataset for this line. Instead of train_dataset you should give val_dataset. You Val.Acc is high because you are validating on the training dataset itself.

```
 valloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=SubsetRandomSampler(valid_idx))
```

Comment: Im trying to do the cross validation so i used subsampling option is this right to use?